# Display content not updated from specific date

Tags: views, datetime

I can generate a views with provides a list of content has been updated from an specific date (by adding field "Content: Updated date" in Filter criteria). However, I cannot find the opposite option, I mean built a list from a specific date which has not been moderated or updated. How can I get it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

When you create your filter criteria you have an `Operator` drop down list that will offer the option like `Is not equal to` or `is empty (NULL)`

Then you can expose this filter and set the date manually or use an offset from the current date.